# ion-nav-back-button not working in ionic v1

Tags: ionic-framework

Good day, Im been working on my project for a long time, and I noticed something not working. This is my config.

```
.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/auth/login.html',
    controller: 'AuthCtrl as auth'
})

.state('signup', {
    url: '/signup',
    templateUrl: 'templates/auth/signup.html',
    controller: 'AuthCtrl as auth'
})
```

and I have this button on my **login.html**

```
<button class="button button-block button-balanced button-small" ng-click="auth.goToSignUp()">Signup</button>
```

which navigates to the signup page. The problem is that, when im on my **signup.html**, pressing the *ion-nav-back-button* does not go back to the login page.
I tried searching for some solutions but so far none of which solved my problem.
Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: what is your code on the click for auth.goToSignup()  function?

Comment: @HardikDG  $state.go('signup');

Comment: it should work then, else you can try with $ionicHistory if it works for you

Comment: @HardikDG, apparently its not working.

Comment: @HardikDG, how do i use $ionicHistory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the nav-back-button as show in the [ionic docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/1.2.1/api/directive/ionNavBackButton/) with $state.go

Recommended markup for default settings:

```
<ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

With custom inner markup, and automatically adds a default click action:

```
<ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
    <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

If the above didn't work for you, you can try with [$ionicHistory](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/1.2.1/api/service/$ionicHistory/)

```
<ion-nav-bar ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"
    ng-click="myGoBack()">
    <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

//In your controller
function MyCtrl($scope, $ionicHistory) {
  $scope.myGoBack = function() {
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
  };
```

Also, make sure your $ionicHistory is storing the history and you have added that in the controller's dependency list

you can check the current history with `$ionicHistory.viewHistory()`